# onActivityResult for several intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I have several intent using `startActivityforResult()` to launch. I want to receive several feedbacks. How can I write `onActivityResult()` for each `startActivityforResult()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass in the requestCode as second argument to startActivityForResult. This integer value will be return to you in onActivityResult as requestCode.

Say you calling with different request codes.

```
 startActivityForResult(i1, 1);

 startActivityForResult(i2, 2);
```

Then your onActivityResult looks like:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  switch (requestCode) {
     case 1:
       // do what u hv to do for first start activity
     break;
     case 2:
       // for second start activity
     break;
  }
}
```

In Activity 2 which is launched by you use following apis to return the data:

```
public final void setResult (int resultCode)
public final void setResult (int resultCode, Intent data) // If you want to pass some data
```

Read below docs for more details:

[Starting Activities and getting results back](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities)

[onActivityResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult%28int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent%29)

Comment: if I write my second intent to call another activity 2. In activity 2, need I create a new intent named "data" instead of other name when overriding finish() method?